# When destroying a mortar with spells, should you attack close or far from the one you destroyed?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I like dropping a couple lightning spells to destroy a mortar. I usually use this when raiding with barch (and a few giants in CC).

My question is: is it better to deploy troops in the area that just got clear of the clan castle, or do you actually want to deploy them to where the remaining mortars are so they can be taken out quickly? I usually find bases are designed so mortar range overlaps a bit. I'm TH 8 if that matters.

Comment: I would say that this is very situational, it completely depends on the defending layout and what you want out of it. I assume resources so where are they, and are they in the 'death zone' of the remaining mortars. How long will you last if you don't take them out, and how many troops will you have left if you do try to take out the mortars. I think this question may be a little too open ended

Comment: I would agree, it really depends on the situation.  things like the level of the mortars (is it a rushed th or an almost max base) can really sway where i deploy in relation to mortars or storages.

Answer (score 1):

I would say attack the other mortars. Attack the closest one to the outer walls so you can get rid of that quickly so it won't wipe out your troops. Attacking near the mortar will cause your troops to be attacked by the other mortars and when you're using a lot of barbs and archers and relatively weak troops, they can be wiped out pretty fast from what I know from personal experience

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If you go for a high % with 2-3 stars, I would say go for the other mortars.

If you consentrate on farming, you should take advantage of that the one side has no mortar left. When doing this, take out the mortar with spells that are covering most recources so you get most out of it.

Comment: This is what i thought. :)